# Synchronized does not force thread to wait

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

### Background

There two threads in my game. The game loop itself and a completable future that fetches some stuff from the database and should wait till the end of the frame to communicate with the game. My simplified code looks like this.

```java
public class GameExtension extends SFSExtension{  // Im using a server framework, ignore this here

    private World world;
    
    @Override
    public void init() {

        // Inits the event handler used later on to create the future, removed that part for shorting the code
        // Just passes the world as a lock.
         
        ///////////////////////
        // Loop
        ///////////////////////

        // Game loop thread
        var taskScheduler = SmartFoxServer.getInstance().getTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {

             // Synchronize world acess to prevent issues with multithreading
             synchronized(world) {
                 world.setDelta(deltaTime);
                 world.process();     // At some point theres a event dispatched which creates the future... that invokes the method of the class below
             }
            
        }, 0,1000/60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}


/**
 * A event handler, creates a completable future
 */
public final class LoadChunksEventHandler {

    private World world;
    public LoadChunksEventHandler(World world) { this.world = world; }

    @Subscribe
    public void OnLoadChunksEvent(LoadChunksEvent event){

        // Execute query
        var idsTask = resultTask.thenApply(objects -> {... });
        var loadTask = idsTask.thenCompose(pairs -> ...);
        loadTask.thenAccept(entityPojos -> {

            // Convert pojos to ingame objects
            synchronized (world) {

                // Acesses the world and uses its methods
                var entities = persistence.getMapper().<IntBag, Collection<EntityPojo>>demap(mergedPojos);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### The problem

I want to achieve following behaviour. The completable future, which gets created somewhere during `world.process()`, should wait for the scheduled game loop thread to release the world (Waiting for the frame to end). That way the completablefuture is able to acess the game world safely.

The problem here is... currently that synchronized statement gets... ignored ? I have the problem that the game continues to run the statements in its synchronized block, when the completablefuture is already in its own synchronized block. Both threads are using the safe `world` lock. So i dont understand why they are not waiting for each other ? Till the other one finished its block and released the world.

CommonPoolWorker-5 is the future
Meanwhile... pool 1 thread 2 is the game loop.
This screenshot was made when i was inside the futures syncronized block. A clear sign that both are running async.

[image: The thread dump]

### The question

Why doesnt the game loop thread wait for the completablefuture thread and the otherway around ? They are both using the same lock object... isnt that enough ? How do i achieve that the created completable future/its thread waits till the game released the world and the other way around ?

`Game enters its syncronized block -> Creates the future -> Exits the block -> Future gets resolved -> Enters the futures block -> Game waits on the world resource -> Future exits its block -> Game continues`

Im glad for any help on that topic !

Comment: What does “the game released the world” mean? You can only use `synchronized` on already existing objects, so how is the synchronization supposed to know that this already existing object has not been “released”? If there is an additional condition like “being released” you want to wait for, you have to implement exactly that.

Comment: This can happen only if both code blocks are being run by the same thread. Is the event being dispatched and processed in the same thread? If yes, are you sure that the DB fetch (the one being wrapped by the CompletableFuture) is executing in a different thread? If so, can you include the code which demonstrates that?